# Pycharm does not have right access to /app/pycharm.Please run it by privileged user to update

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, updates

I am using linux mint 19.3 cinnamon version, Pycharm 20.1 version and I get an option to update it to Pycharm 20.1.1 but I am not able to do it and the follwing window pops up can anyone help me solve this problem[image]

Comment: Any chances that the Pycharm instance you're running is in fact a snap package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the PyCharm with sudo privileges. Sudo stands for root access in Unix systems.

Type on the terminal: `sudo [py_charm_app_executable]`, then it'll simply have write access to filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening pycharm with nautilus giving it root privileges. I had the same issue but i managed to solve it with the help of nautilus.

Comment: I am a noob in linux, do you mind elaborating please...i didn't get you

Comment: install nautilus:- sudo apt-get install nautilus                                                                    after that............run nautilus:- nautilus

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is originally for `ubuntu`, but I had it on Mac (macOS 14.2.1) and running it using `sudo` doesn't help me. [Link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/424089) on how to run as root in Mac though.

What helped me, was updating the ownership of the folder to myself, and then back to root:

```bash
cd /Applications/PyCharm.app
sudo chown -R <your username>:staff Contents
```

I have updated PyCharm (as many times as required, for me to 2023.3.4) and returned the ownership back to root:

```bash
sudo chown -R root:Admin Contents
```